# Lock and unlock a semaphore from different threads in Cocoa

Tags: multithreading, cocoa, synchronization, nslock

I need to use some kind of semaphore to protect the access to a mutex zone, but I need this zone to span multiple threads. This is what I found in the documentation:

> Warning: The NSLock class uses POSIX
>   threads to implement its locking
>   behavior. When sending an unlock
>   message to an NSLock object, you must
>   be sure that message is sent from the
>   same thread that sent the initial lock
>   message. Unlocking a lock from a
>   different thread can result in
>   undefined behavior.

I remember I read around that this is a way to prevent programming errors. Is this statement correct?
I read the threading guide from the documentation but I can't find any other class to use that allows lock and unlock from different threads. Is there any other solution in Cocoa to do this?
Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`NSCondition`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSCondition_class/Reference/Reference.html).

Comment: I supposed it suffered the same limitations. Instead, it is working perfectly it seems. Thanks!